# Can i make a thread which run after every 5 sec and update a views value in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

I am making a thread in android to update a views value after every 5 sec.But i am getting this exception:-

```
"E/AndroidRuntime(30793): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
```

Is there any other alternative to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you are using thread to update the UI.

1.use handler [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to update UI from thread
2 you can also use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) onProgressUpdate(Progress...) to update ui,

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Timer Task that fetches the value ( a thread could do ) and use a handler to pass on the value to the UI thread. Views can be updated only from the main/ UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to use a recursive function inside a background thread and wait at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler for this for example :

Handler handle = null;
Runnable runnable = null;

in onCreate(){   // method

```
handler = new Handler();
handler.post(runnable);
```

runnable = new Runnable(){

void run(){

```
 handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);// run will be call in every 1 seconds

 // your code here to implement it will execute in every i second
```

}
}

}